# Bootstrap table split cells

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following strange thing happening.
I have the following table:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Паша</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Паша</td>
        <td>Паша 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

It works fine as long as I don't add the boostrap table class. Without class it looks like this:

[image]

But as soon as I add the bootstrap table class, it looks like this

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Паша</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Паша</td>
        <td>Паша 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Any idea what is happening here?

P.S. Sorry can't see pictures in my country (maybe some block?). Adding theese for reference.

Pics not showing properly here are the links
Without boostrap - https://ikeen.com/img/blog/t1.jpg
With bootstrap - https://ikeen.com/img/blog/t2.jpg

Comment: Pics not showing properly here are the links
Withour boostrap - https://ikeen.com/img/blog/t1.jpg
With bootstrap - https://ikeen.com/img/blog/t2.jpg

Comment: Am I the only one not seeing the pics? Looks like img provider not available in my country.

Comment: Your code should work fine... How'd you nest bootstrap to your project? Did you use CDN?

Comment: Looks like either my intnernet or Stack are having problems. It's local.

Comment: I really cannot figure out, what could be the reason for that behavour. The only advice i can give you at this point is to try setting up bootstrap from scratch into your project. You can grab the source-files at [getbootstrap.com (bootstrap v4.6.0)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/download/).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot figure out what is the exact reason for that strange behavior. Perhaps, It might be the problem with the bootstrap version that you set up locally. Try to update it or use CDN. You can find them at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/download/

I used `bootstrap 4.6.0` as below and it worked fine.

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
   <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Паша</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Паша</td>
            <td>Паша 2</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>        
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how and why but this seems to work. I think there is a problem with  tag in bootstrap

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tbody>
    <tr>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Безлимитный интернет на скорости 40 Мбит в секунду</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Всего за 4500 тенге в месяц</td>
        <td>Оборудование в подарок</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```